# Changing fc-highlight when dragging events on calendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

When [dragging an event](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/demos/external-dragging.html) on the calendar there's a light blue-ish color that appears, I think it's [.fc-highlight class](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/5af235874b3fd95b57ec9f632e2e8b9e8c26f6c3/src/common/common.scss#L20) that determines the color but trying to override it with css doesn't seem to work, neither does there appear to be any [draggable callbacks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing) I can use to change it

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this question doesn't provide enough detail to be answerable. Is there a Fullcalendar forum you can ask this question on? You might have a better chance of getting an answer there.

Comment: hm yep I could try looking around thanks!

Comment: @kismert according to fullCalendar's support page, this _is_ the fullCalendar forum :-) https://fullcalendar.io/support

Comment: @ADyson well you get what you pay for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property is set in the fullCalendar CSS file using `background`, rather than `background-color` so you need to use that to override it:

```
.fc-highlight
{
  background: red;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/948/